# Eloquent User Where Clause with Entrust Library

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, roles, entrust

I'm trying to select all users for a company. But only users who has "admin" role status (Entrust, etc.).

```
User::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->hasRole('admin')->get();
```

The above is throwing an error. Left a bit lost on how to run such a query. Where am I going wrong with this? Very little documentation on Entrust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain Eloquent for this. The [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method would generate one query:

```
$users = User::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
             ->whereHas('roles', function($query) {
                 $query->where('name', 'admin');
             })->get();
```

Or, you can just get the roles and then get all of that role's users. This would generate two queries, but ultimately achieve the same thing.

```
$users = Role::where('name', 'admin')
             ->first()
             ->users()
             ->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
             ->get();
```

Comment: First option is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to get all the users having the `company_id` first

```
$users = User::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->get();
```

Then loop through `$users` and check `hasRole()`

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
        if($user->hasRole('admin')){
        //user is admin
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This might be a dirty solution but you can try to do a manual query

```
$admin = DB::table('role_user')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
        ->where('roles.name', 'admin')->get();
```